# Jquery detect form submission and scroll to div

Tags: jquery

I try this script to click into a search button and scroll to the list of results.

It is not scrolling after the form submission as expected.

How can i use JQuery to detect the form submission ?

My goal is to scroll to the element identified by resultList id!

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $("#searchResults").click(function (){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#resultList").offset().top
            }, 1000);
        });
});
```

Cakephp :

```
echo $this->Form->end('Search', array('id'=>'searchResults'));

<div id='resultList'>
```

Comment: your code looks fine but you are checking click event on form. Check submit instead if you are using submit button. click will use only if you are using button type button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your form an id, then try changing

`$("#searchResults").click`

to

`$('#formId').submit`

And consider using a return false if your form submit is causing a page load.

Comment: The original post looks like a mix of languages and isn't really clear. My answer should still work regardless :)

Comment: he is using any coding framework by which it seems mix

Comment: Hi i am using Cakephp and Jquery

Comment: $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#ConsultForm').on('submit', function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                 scrollTop: $("#table-list").offset().bottom
            }, 2000);
            return false;
        });
    });